# cannot get rc.local to work with simple chown script on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I am a bit of a noob and I have been following this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/use-etc-rc-local-boot/) to setup rc.local on ubuntu 20.04 as I want to change ownership of folder on boot.

The script is saved in chownscript.sh and it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
chown -R 1001:1001 /opt/redis
exit 0
```

When I run it as `sudo ./chownscript.sh` it works fine.

My rc.local file is

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Ensure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# To enable or disable this script, just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default, this script does nothing.

sh /opt/chownscript.sh

exit 0
```

My /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service file is

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targ[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
Type=forking
```

when i run `systemctl status rc-local.service` i get

```
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             └─debian.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2023-03-29 19:55:53 UTC; 16min ago
    Process: 651 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 24ms

Mar 29 19:55:53 ubuntu-server-2 systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Mar 29 19:55:53 ubuntu-server-2 sudo[653]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/chown -R 1001:1001 /opt/redis
Mar 29 19:55:53 ubuntu-server-2 sudo[653]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 29 19:55:53 ubuntu-server-2 sudo[653]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 29 19:55:53 ubuntu-server-2 systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

However when I check folder permisions nothing has changed. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would try using /bin/bash instead of sh shell

Comment: Updated script to bin/bash. It works if I run "bash -x /etc/rc.local", but does not appear to work on reboot.

Comment: Why do you have "sudo chown", when rc.local is run as root anyway? Try including full path to chown in script.

Comment: I only used sudo when trying to run the script myself to check it worked. The rc.local file does not have sudo in it. The script does not have sudo in it either.